# Add value to the CSS class in directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I use Angular 10 in my project.

I have directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHoverImage]'
})
export class HoverImageDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener("mouseenter") onMouseEnter(){

    const imageurl = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('src');
    
    //put imageurl to the background-image of the expand-image css class.
    
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "expand-image");
  }

  @HostListener("mouseleave") onMouseLeave(){
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "expand-image");
  }
}
```

Here is expand-image css class:

```
  .expand-image
  {
    background-image:''
    margin: 150px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: scale(3); /* Standard syntax */
    z-index:999;
  }
```

As you can see onMouseEnter function I fetch from DOM image URL and pit it to the image variable.
Then I attach the expand-image class to the element on which mouse hover occurred.

My question is how can I add to the expand-image CSS class to the background-image property the value of the imageurl?

Comment: why add it to the class and not set background-image directly on the host element?

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating a custom CSS tag in which you edit your `.expand-image` property by setting a background-image url. Could be something as follows:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHoverImage]'
})
export class HoverImageDirective {
  private CSSElement: HTMLStyleElement;
  private CSSId: string;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.CSSElement = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.append(this.CSSElement);
  }

  @HostListener("mouseenter") onMouseEnter() {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    const imageurl = nativeElement.getAttribute('src');
    this.CSSElement.innerHTML = `.expand-image {
            background-image: url(${imageUrl});
        }`

    //put imageurl to the background-image of the expand-image css class.

    this.renderer.addClass(nativeElement, "expand-image");
  }

  @HostListener("mouseleave") onMouseLeave() {
    this.CSSElement.innerHTML = '';
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.removeClass(nativeElement, "expand-image");
  }
}
```

Basically, your directive will create a `<style>` tag, which you can edit directly by using `.innerHTML` property and setting a background url for your class. You can also get rid of your `background-image` rule which is currently present inside your CSS file.

I couldn't test it, but it should work.

Otherwise, you could have a look at `.insertRule` method of Javascript, but you will need to select a stylesheet first.

Have a look at the [related docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) to learn more about this other option you could try

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Renderer2's setStyle API and achieve what you need:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "background-image", imageurl);
```

and on mouseleave you can remove the style (either by saving the previous value as a state in the directive or by setting it to null, and then resetting to that on mouseleave)